# Which is feasible technology to implement office add-in for word

Tags: office-js, office-addins

We've been relying on Angular for our system development, but now we're looking to create an Office add-in for Word using Angular. However, we've discovered that the Angular for Office add-in project has been archived as per below link.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-TaskPane-Angular

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-Angular2-StyleChecker

Here are our questions:

Can we continue to use Angular for our project, given our current needs and goals?

If not, are there other technologies or frameworks that you suggest could be better suited and more efficient for our system development?

We're also interested in knowing if there's a recommended technology with assured long-term support for Office add-in development.

Comment: It's unclear what your requirements are.  But If you're comfortable with Angular, then you're probably open to other Javascript solutions.  Look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/develop-overview.

Comment: Our goal with Office Add-ins was to bring Web Programming to Office so you're welcome to use whatever web framework you're most comfortable with for programming. It's hard for us to maintain samples across many of these frameworks and so occasionally we have to scale back.  The framework that we use the most internally is React since it underpins a lot of our Fluent UI and its the one we have the best support for.

Answer (score 0):

use can easily create office js add-in using Visual Studio 2022.
and also you can use angularjs here this is very simple to use angularjs is visual studio project.